# Substituting an expression inside another one

Tags: python, sympy

I have a formula, which I read as a string from a file:

```
file_eq = pd.read_excel("Equations.xlsx")
formula1 = file_eq["Formula1"]
eq1 = parse_expr(formula)
```

The equation, when printed, looks like this: 1/sqrt(1 - v**2/c **2).

Then I read a second expression

```
formula2 = file_eq["Formula2"]
eq2 = parse_expr(formula2)
```

which is: v**1.0/c

I want to replace the second formula with a new variable whenever it appears in the first formula. So I tried this:

```
x = symbols('x')
eq1 = eq1.subs(eq2, x)
```

But nothing changes. What I should have obtained in the end is: 1/sqrt(1 - x**2)

On the other hand, if I do it manually (but I can't do this for the purpose of my project, because I have many equations), like this:

```
v = symbols('v')
c = symbols('c')
eq1 = eq1.subs(v/c, x)
```

I get the right answer. Can someone tell me what to do to get what the expression I want? Thank you!